# Can't initialize a new Rails application within the directory of another, please change to a non-Rails directory first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting this error:

```
Can't initialize a new Rails application within the directory of another, please change to a non-Rails directory first
```

But I'm not in a rails directory, I'm on the desktop. There's no .bundle files anywhere to be found. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you run `rails c`? If that starts a rails console, what is the `RAILS_ROOT`?

Comment: You made a Rails project somewhere in your current directory tree at some point.

Comment: When I run rails c I get Could not find rails-3.2.12 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems. I've run that once before but it didn't fix the root problem, and I feel like is a symptom of the root problem.

Answer (score 9):

1. cd bin/
2. rm -rf rails

This fixed my problem. I was also getting the same error message

"Can't initialize a new Rails application within the directory of another, please change to a non-Rails directory first.
Type 'rails' for help."

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this over the weekend, but after lots of prodding and poking got it to work.

The problem for me was that Aptana (I believe) created a second rails script in my local bin directory (`~/bin`) which was called instead of the system script. This local version was older than `/usr/local/bin/rails`. After moving aside `~/bin/rails`, "rails new fred" worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new folder or rails app in root folder, under ~/

Comment: I get Could not find rails-3.2.12 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems. I've run bundle install once before and it still left me with the same problem.

Comment: Did you created your rails app within root folder like this: `rails new first_app`

Comment: Yep. That's what it throws me when I try to do that.

Comment: create a directory under rails_projects first, `mkdir first_app`, then run your `rails new first_app` command.

If first_app already exists, remove it first or pick another directory/application name.

Comment: Ok I ran bundle install just to get that out of the way and now we're back to the original "can't install in a rails app" problem. It's like there's no scenario in which I'm not in a directory that has rails installed no matter how deep I go

Comment: Probably you might be creating rails app within an existing rails app. Try a fresh start by creating within root folder or some other place which will automatically run bundle install there. Then try rails c to test whether application runs or not.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem this morning and that's because rails was already been there while i was creating my application.

To remove the error just go to bin folder of your application and remove the rails folder, and try to create new rails application in your planned folder using ***rails new app_name***.

[image]